# How to access the document object model?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am learning about manipulating the DOM w/ javascript.

I understood that JS can only access the DOM in a browser-environment, because the DOM is only available in the browser, and JS, being a "client-side" language, can run on the browser, access the DOM, and manipulate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const heading = document.querySelector("h1");

console.log(heading);
```

Every time I tried to access the 'document' object before, I got:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I was using the "run" button on the visual studio code IDE., The given error was displayed on the IDE's panel (output section). I didn't open it on the browser. I know VSCode is not a browser-environment. What is another way I can configure my code, so it will be able to access the DOM?

I went inside my HTML document that I have used the "Live Server" extension to run (on VSCode), right-clicked to inspect, and the javascript code **works alright** *inside* the browser, because the DOM is accessible within the browser. It seems impractical to write code in the IDE and then go to the DevTools on the browser to check if everything is correct every 5 seconds. Is there any way to correlate my IDE, the webpage, and the DOM instead of inspecting the HTML document after every refresh?

Comment: How are you running this code?  Are you opening this page in a browser?  Something else?

Comment: the reason its ReferenceError might beacuse the document is not loaded yet try to wrap it in windows.onload = function(){ ..... }; you can also move your script declaration after the body.

Comment: I am using the "run" button on the visual studio code IDE., The given error was displayed on the IDE's panel (output section). I didn't open it on the browser.

Comment: @ramimamedov: Do you mean that VSCode is executing some terminal/command-line operation?  If you're just executing the JavaScript code on the command-line with `node` then, no, there is no DOM.  (And in that case the HTML is irrelevant, it's not being used.)  You need to open your web page in a browser in order for it to be opened in a browser.

Comment: This is exactly the case David. I am not yet familiar with any other way to open my "webpage" in a browser. Only thing I have done is using the "Live Server" extension in VSCode to run my .html file on the browser. Is there a way to get the "JS" section running on the browser, (as a webpage) that I am unaware of?

Comment: The thing is, I went inside my HTML document that I have used the "Live Server" extension to run (on VSCode), right-clicked to inspect, and the code was working inside the browser, because the DOM is accessible within the browser. It seems impractical to write code in the IDE and then go to the DevTools on the browser to check if everything is correct every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your script inside your IDE (Visual Studio Code), there is no access to the DOM because it does not exist for your script. Your script will only work if it is executed within an HTML page. If you include your script in this way and open the HTML file in your browser, you can click 'Inspect' and navigate to the console. You will then see the heading printed out.

Comment: I went inside my HTML document that I have used the "Live Server" extension to run (on VSCode), right-clicked to inspect, and the javascript code works alright (as you said) inside the browser, because the DOM is accessible within the browser.  Is there any way to correlate my IDE, the webpage, and the DOM instead of inspecting the HTML document after every refresh?

Comment: That isn't possible, why would you like to do that ?

Comment: If that is not possible, I will just inspect my html document, and check if my javascript is behaving correctly in the browser's console (DevTools). I only asked to be sure there is not a better practice to access DOM manipulation which I was not aware of.